# In logic, is 'P = Q,' where P and Q are propositions, ill-conceived?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, meta-math

In formal/mathematical logic, what are the rules governing "identity" (equals sign) use? Why is it that a conditional (or in certain instances a biconditional) sign is used instead to show a relation between propositions.

I'm a high school student with a developing interest in logic, so any insight into the philosophy guiding the semantics of logical languages would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Edit:
Thank you for your responses. I have two fallacious arguments written propositionally: If P, then Q If P, then R Therefore: If Q, then R And If P, then Q If R, then Q Therefore: If P, then R However, if these particular propositions were interpreted as being connected not by a conditional sign but by an "=" (identity) sign, wouldn't we have examples of the transitive property (i.e. P=Q, P=R, so Q=R using the rule of identity elimination in Fitch calculus)? However, neither conditional/biconditional introduction/elimination would be able to prove this in Fitch. Is this why it's a bad idea to use "=" when translating to the more primitive language of propositional logic?

Comment: Your use of symbols $P$ and $Q$ for propositions suggests an *abstract* interpretation, in which a proposition is an "atomic" entity (no "internal" structure), in which case it makes sense to consider propositions are either equal (the same) or not equal (different, capable of being assigned independent truth values).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have two  fallacious arguments written propositionally:

If P, then Q
If P, then R
Therefore: If Q, then R
And

If P, then Q
If R, then Q
Therefore: If P, then R
However, if these particular propositions were interpreted as being connected not by a conditional sign but by an "=" (identity) sign, wouldn't we have examples of the transitive property (i.e. P=Q, P=R, so Q=R)? Is this why it's a bad idea to use "=" when translating to the more primitive language of propositional logic?

Comment: No, equality, implication and  biimplication are all transitive relations.

Comment: Or I guess "identity elimination" is what it's sometimes called, the use of the transitive property.

Comment: Thanks, Rob Arthan. I think I do understand why they're transitive--but the using the conditional in that case certainly creates a fallacy

Comment: But = doesn't, right?

Comment: It couldn't be proven from a biconditional sign either, I don't think. Using the valid rule of inference "biconditional elimination" wouldn't get you anywhere. I apologize if I'm being confusing, but that's what I mean to say when I talk about differences between signs. Is that why the  "=" must be reserved for relations in multi-place predicates?

Comment: These are the Fitch calculus rules to which I'm referring: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~brianwc/courses/logic/rulesummary.html

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing ill-conceived about thinking of what is usually written as $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ or $P \leftrightarrow Q$ as an equation between the propositions denoted by $P$ and $Q$. However, it is conventional in mathematical logic **not** to use the equals sign for this relation.

This convention avoids various kinds of ambiguity and fits in well with the concepts of first-order logic (where we have a specific universe of discourse in mind, like natural number arithmetic, in which equality denotes equality of natural numbers, while bi-implication denotes equivalence of propositions about the natural numbers).

There are higher-order logics in which the world of propositions forms part of the universe of discourse and then bi-implication just becomes a special case of equality.

There is a separate question of notation for syntactic identity between linguistic constructs. I.e., the notation to use when we are thinking of $1 + 2$ or $A\land B$ as sequences of symbols not expressions that denote numbers or truth values. The symbol $=$ is often used for syntactic identity, but this usage can give rise to confusion: using $\equiv$ or $:=$ is a common way of avoiding this.

Comment: So CpCqp = CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCpqCCqrCpr=CCNppp, ApNp=CCpCqrCqCpr and so on for all pairs of tautologies?

Comment: It's also convenient to have $\iff$ as a more primitive notion than $=$, we can define $=$ to be the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $P(a)\iff P(b)$ for all predicates with a parameter. This simplifies the logical language a bit, I believe.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: yes that's [Leibnitz's law of the identity of indiscernibles](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/). I don't think it makes any simplifications to the **language** of higher-order logic.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: yes, when translated out of the ancient notation that you insist on using, classical logical equivalences are equations (identities) over boolean algebras.

Comment: @RobArthan Isn't that actually grouping all tautologies under an equivalence class, and then just checking equality between the classes of two **distinct** tautologies?

Comment: If you are talking about my comment about identities over boolean algebras then no: two tautologies are in the same equivalence class. Formulas such as  $x \land y$ and $y \land x$ where $x$ and $y$ are variables are equivalent but not tautologies.

Comment: From the semantic point of view, P and Q often don't denote propositions, but serve as variables for propositions.  They might sometimes denote propositions, but not when doing computations with truth values.  '1' and '0', aren't propositions, but rather logical constants.

Answer (score 6):

The equality sign could be used between propositions, but they would need to be *equal*, that is, they would need to be the same proposition.

One reason for using biconditional is that it can link propositions that are not equal, but which have the same truth value. For example, "English has 26 letters" and "Hydrogen has one electron" are both true, but they are not the *same*. So we would not write an equal sign between them, but we could write a biconditional between them.

In propositional logic, we are often much more concerned with whether propositions have the truth value than whether they are the same - to the point that the equality sign is often left out altogether.

Comment: +1. For the OP, here's an example in pure propositional logic: consider the sentences "$A$" and "$A\vee A$." They are definitely equivalent, but are the "the same" sentence? I would say *no* - they are different strings of symbols.

Comment: "English has 26 letters"  I suppose that holds if lower case letters and upper case letters in modern (or it looks like Olde also) English have their usual correspondence.  But, a and A, at the very least, are not merely size transformations of each other.  Nor are q and Q.  Nor are r and R.  though maybe the above sentences weren't in english.  MAYBE ONLY THESE LAST TWO SENTENCES ARE IN ENGLISH.

Comment: So, apparently, both Carl and Noah are unhappy that $1 + 2 = 2 + 1$ and that $0 = 0 + 0$.  Hmm?

Comment: @RobArthan I upvoted your comment, but it depends. What is "$0$" and "$0+0$"? In a purely syntactical description, I could say that $(0)$ and $(0,+,0)$ are different as, say, strings. Which is the approach Carl's answer seem to be taking.

Comment: In algebra, it is common to write an equals sign between expressions that evaluate to the same value. One of the first places this seems to break is in abstract algebra, where for the first time distinct polynomials over a finite field can produce the same polynomial function. In logic, however, it just isn't common to put equality signs between different propositions that evaluate to the same truth value.

Comment: @RobArthan Good point, I was being sloppy. For me the difference is this: we largely agree that the purpose of a string like "$0+1$" is to denote a number, and (with minor exceptions) there's rarely any serious confusion over what sort of number such strings can denote. By contrast, I'm not at all convinced that the string of symbols "$A\vee A$" denotes merely its truth value (I'm also not convinced that this *isn't* the case), and indeed the question of denotation here is quite messy. So for me that's the distinction - when the kind of denotation is unclear, I go strict.

Comment: @CarlMummert What does it mean "to evaluate to the same value"?

Comment: $1+3$ and $2+ 2$ are distinct expressions that evaluate to the same value in the ring of natural numbers.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD That sentence doesn't have a meaning as it is. It's saying "if they have the same semantics" but this requires to first *define* what the semantics is (denotational or operational? what is the domain? etc.).  The point is: we often assume a certain domain for these expressions and a common form of reduction.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you find it more sensible to use equality instead of  $\leftrightarrow $ with the same purpose, it is mostly a matter of convenience; we already use the symbol of equality for other purposes.

If you mean you want the proposition "P = Q" to mean something like "P and Q are identical": in typical logical languages, formulas or propositions range over whatever the domain of the model is. For example, if we are considering the first order logic of graph theory (i.e. with one binary relation), a formula should have a truth value based on what graph it is interpreted in, and what vertices are assigned to its free variables.

If we allow a construction like "if P, Q are formulas, then P = Q is also a formula", then the interpretation of this sentence would have to depend not on the structure of a graph, but on the syntactic information of the formulas P and Q. This is simply not what we want the propositions to be "allowed" to express.

Comment: +1: It looks to me that it was Carl rather than the OP who raised the spectre of syntactic identity.

Comment: @Rob The phrase "what are the rules governing 'identity'" made me think that perhaps OP was asking why the equals sign was allowed between terms, but not between formulas.

Comment: I was supporting your answer, not criticising it.

Answer (score 3):

First-order logic already uses = for identity on the domain under discussion (sets, integers or whatever). So even though we could conceivably use = for identity on truth values, it's clearer to have a different symbol $\leftrightarrow$.

Plus the notation $P \leftrightarrow Q$ has the advantage of suggesting $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q \rightarrow P$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first person to use the '=' sign was [Robert Recorde in 1557](http://www.qsponge.com/questions/76792508/Who_invented_the_equal_sign).  In translation Recorde says "And to avoid the tedious repetition of these words : is equal to : I will set a pair of parallel lines thus: =, because no two things can be more equal."

So one might ask, if you wrote an equals sign between logically different, yet truth-functionally equivalent, propositions would they qualify as two things which can't be more equal?  Having studied the consequences of the forms of certain propositions, I've found that the consequences of those forms can end up as very different even when those forms qualify as having the same truth-value.  So, I do not think it correct to write '=' between propositions.

A distinct answer: P and Q are not propositions, unless specified and oftentimes they are not specified. They serve as variables for propositions. Writing p = q or equivalently a = b or equivalently c = f would literally mean that the variables were equal.

There is no case where P and Q qualify as propositions.  It just doesn't qualify as coherent or makes for wording that could use revision for clarity.  P and Q may *represent* propositions, but that is all.  Considering P and Q as propositions makes for a counterfactual situation.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote -- it's a good answer with informative historical context.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I disagree with the answer. The = symbol, were it to be used here, would assert that the two propositions have the same truth value (or truth values that couldn't be any more equal, if you prefer) in the model under consideration, not that they have the same consequences from a proof-theoretic view.